# Rails - Dynamic query all records from has_many association with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Building that has many residents. My index page list all buildings with a link to list all residents   from that building. I'm learning ROR again, and I'm struggling to create this view.

Here is what I got so far.

**../models/building.rb**

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :residents
end
```

**../models/resident.rb**

```
class Resident < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
end
```

**..controllers/buildings_controller.rb**

Here is where I start to get lost. In my show action I don't know how to pass the params to generate a view with all residents from a building using link_to. I'm not sure how I can do it.
Or how to do a query like  r = Resident.all.where(:building_id => 1), but dynamically.

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @building = Building.all
end

def show
  @building = Building.find(params[:id])
  @buildings = Building.all
end
```

**..views/buildings/index.rb**

```
  <% @building.each do |b| %>
    <div>
      <%= link_to b.name, '/buildings/show/'b.id %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I'm open to different approaches...

Thank you community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the named routes feature in Ruby on Rails: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

*Creating a resourceful route will also expose a number of helpers to the controllers in your application. In the case of resources :photos:
photos_path returns /photos*

```
new_photo_path returns /photos/new
edit_photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id/edit (for instance, edit_photo_path(10) returns /photos/10/edit)
photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10) returns /photos/10)
```

*Each of these helpers has a corresponding _url helper (such as photos_url) which returns the same path prefixed with the current host, port, and path prefix.*

So to be able to reach your controller, you have to add some routes to your routes.rb file and use it in your view:

```
# routes.rb
  resources :buildings
  resources :residents


# index view
  <% @building.each do |b| %>
    <div>
      <%= link_to b.name, building_path(b) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

# show view to show all residents, belonging to a building
  <% @building.residents.each do |resident| %>
    <div>
      <%= link_to resident.name, resident_path(resident) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```